# JS - resize font depending on DIV size

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div class="container" and a "p" element inside of it.
Is there a simple JS way to resize font depending on the parent DIV widht and height?
Please find the code below.

```
<div class="container">
<p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

The whole idea is to create a CSS template to quickly add divs to HTML code.

The project is to create layout similar to Windows Phone with bigger and smaller rectangles and squares.

Now, because each div may have different dimentions, thus, to avoid setting font parameter to each of the div, I'd like to add JS script that would proportionally (%) change the font size depending on the size of the div (but taking into consideration both width and height because both can change).

Please note that divs, once set, will not change dimentions with resizing browser window, therefore using "vw" and "vh" parameter in CSS is probably not a correct approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 50vw;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not it.
My project is that I have multiple boxes (divs) and inside each box I have some p elements. Now, these boxes have different shapes, some are square, some rectangle. Depending on the size I would need to change the font size as well.
Having that dependant on the size of a browser window is slightly different.

Comment: No idea about JS  for this but It will be better to use media queries for doing this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about it?